# Google Analytics for medium.com sites

Tags: google-analytics, medium.com-publishing-api

I have an account on https://medium.com/ and I have linked own domain https://flancer32.com/ to my Medium's account (`Settings / Accounts / Custom domain`). Is it possible to add Google Analytics to "my website" flancer32.com?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you add custom code to your web templates?

Comment: I cannot add custom JS code to my stories on Medium.com. There is WYSIWG editor there.